# EB CLI create failed with error: TypeError - expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm first time I deploy an nodejs expresss application to AWS using EB CLI follow by [aws guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-codecommit.html)

First step, I run ***eb init*** success.

Next step, I run ***eb create my-env*** to create an environment. And I get a error message:

> ERROR: TypeError - expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

**Update**: This's log when I run ***eb logs***

```
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2021/02/24 02:37:43.600169 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreDeployHooks
2021/02/24 02:37:43.600179 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/predeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/02/24 02:37:43.600191 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop X-Ray
2021/02/24 02:37:43.600196 [INFO] stop X-Ray ...
2021/02/24 02:37:43.600212 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf xray.service
2021/02/24 02:37:43.607595 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process xray is not registered 
2021/02/24 02:37:43.607611 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop xray.service
2021/02/24 02:37:43.615106 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop proxy
2021/02/24 02:37:43.615123 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf httpd.service
2021/02/24 02:37:43.623248 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process httpd is not registered, skipping...

2021/02/24 02:37:43.623266 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/02/24 02:37:43.628431 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process nginx is not registered, skipping...

2021/02/24 02:37:43.628457 [INFO] Executing instruction: FlipApplication
2021/02/24 02:37:43.628462 [INFO] Fetching environment variables...
2021/02/24 02:37:43.628470 [INFO] setting default port 8080 to application
2021/02/24 02:37:43.628559 [INFO] Purge old process...
2021/02/24 02:37:43.628593 [INFO] Register application processes...
2021/02/24 02:37:43.628598 [INFO] Registering the proc: web
```

**Update 2:** Now, I deployed my application to AWS EB by manual (upload source zip). I still find and fix above problem.

I search many time but I not found solution to fix it. If you understand my problem, please help me. Thank you so much.

**FINAL UPDATE**: I resolved problem by this [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/43#issuecomment-745553863). problem involve to git config.

Comment: can you share full stack trace?

Comment: @samtoddler I updated logs